# Dealing with null values position when sorting an array based on numeric values

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, sorting, object

[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sorting-mfdvce?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Angular application. I am sorting an array into a `*ngFor` to loop through the results to display in sorted order.

So the question isn't just a simple sort by numeric value. I have a list of users in an Array. Each user has a `sortId` of a number value, that's straightforward. e.g.

```
this.users.sort((a, b) => a.sortId - b.sortId);
```

this will give me a result like:

```
Row 1 - Sort ID: null - original array position: 7
Row 2 - Sort ID: 1 - original array position: 4
Row 3 - Sort ID: 2 - original array position: 1
Row 4 - Sort ID: 3 - original array position: 3
Row 5 - Sort ID: 4 - original array position: 6
Row 6 - Sort ID: 5 - original array position: 8
Row 7 - Sort ID: 6 - original array position: 5
Row 8 - Sort ID: 7 - original array position: 2
```

However, I want to deal with `null` values by just skipping over them, maintain the their position of the original array - so the `null` above will be in the row 7(as its original array position was 7), regardless of whether there is a `sortId` of 7 already. `SortId: 7` will just go into row 8.

Expected result:

```
Row 1 - Sort ID: 1 - original array position: 4
Row 2 - Sort ID: 2 - original array position: 1
Row 3 - Sort ID: 3 - original array position: 3
Row 4 - Sort ID: 4 - original array position: 6
Row 5 - Sort ID: 5 - original array position: 8
Row 6 - Sort ID: 6 - original array position: 5
Row 7 - Sort ID: null - original array position: 7
Row 8 - Sort ID: 7 - original array position: 2
```

Field of users: (the arrayPosition property is just added for demo purposes, so can't be used.)

```
  users = [
    {
      user: 'fred',
      arrayPosition: 1,
      sortId: 2
    },
    {
      user: 'Gen',
      arrayPosition: 2,
      sortId: 7
    },
    {
      user: 'Billy',
      arrayPosition: 3,
      sortId: 3
    },
    {
      user: 'Sid',
      arrayPosition: 4,
      sortId: 1
    },
    {
      user: 'James',
      arrayPosition: 5,
      sortId: 6
    },
    {
      user: 'Tom',
      arrayPosition: 6,
      sortId: 4
    },
    {
      user: 'Jim',
      arrayPosition: 7,
      sortId: null
    },
    {
      user: 'Steve',
      arrayPosition: 8,
      sortId: 5
    }
  ];
```

I have got it working only when the `sortId` was lower than the original array position, otherwise it goes out of order:

```
  this.users.forEach(x => {
    this.fieldsList.splice(x['sortId'] - 1, 0, x);
  });
```

please help me and take a look at the [stackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sorting-mfdvce?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: Perhaps a solution that filters the original list removing null items, sorts that filtered list, then merges that sorted list back into the non-null indices in the original list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved this by sorting all non null values and then adding null in correct indices

```
this.fieldsList = this.users
  .filter(x => x.sortId)
  .sort((a, b) => a.sortId - b.sortId);

this.users.forEach((x, i) => {
  if (x.sortId === null) this.fieldsList.splice(i, 0, x);
});
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/sorting-n2gfvg?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Needed to add my two bits of logic together! thanks

Comment: take a look at https://stackblitz.com/edit/sorting-jybwv9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: You will notice that all values are null apart from two sort values which are 2 and 5. These should be in position 2 and 5. So if there is a smaller sort id than the nulls indices value then the sort id should take priority

Comment: oh I see, will try to find a solution and update the answer